# what virtual device to choose in creating AVD

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij 14 and I am creating AVD, but I am confuse which one should I choose in the phone category. like Nexu S, Nexus one, Nexus 5, Nexus 6, Galaxy Nexus and etc..
can you please help me what device did you choose.

Comment: Select one which fits your needs regarding to screensize and density..

Answer (score 1):

That`s a broad question.
You may choose the device that best suits your needs. If you are looking to develop an application for the Play Store for example, you can find how the market screen sizes are going on by searching on this official Google link:

https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to test your app on emulator that "feels" almost like commercial phone, then you could try to use AVD skins.

Here ([Using a Galaxy Emulator Skin](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-emulator-skin/guide.html)) you can find more information how to emulate Samsung Galaxy phone (by using AVD skins).

Generally, it's quite easy:

0. Download skin for Samsung Galaxy device from [samsung web page](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-emulator-skin/galaxy-s.html)
1. In Android Studio open Device Manager (Tools > Device Manage)
2. You can create a new device (or edit existing one)
3. In Virtual Device Configuration, click New Hardware Profile
4. Then fill in all information regarding to real device that you want to emulate (name, hardware type, screen size, resolution, etc.)
5. Change Default skin for the one you donwloaded (in step 0)
6. Select Android version

Now you can emulate Samsung Galaxy device with Androird Studio to test your app.